# How to get Extract specific *token* value from a long html contect in json response in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

This is the json response i get

{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('-a2cd-7de38353336e')/messages(body)",
"value": [
{
"@odata.etag": "W/"CQAAABYAAADoo/C9sNJWSKsHvdAAD/tOH+"",
"id": "AAMkADIyMDkGQ0NS1iZTEU1NGRhMGQxOABGAAAAAAB8OZ8qhnpAR7k4w9JwOy1qBwDoo-C9sNJWSKN5Ozo5sHvdAAAAAAEMAADoo-C9sNJWSKN5Ozo5sHvdAAEABNMyAAA=",
"body": {
"contentType": "html",
"content": "\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><body style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; margin:0; text-align:center"><div style="width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto; font-size:14px"><div style="background-color:blue; padding:8px 0px; font-family:sans-serif; color:#fff; margin-bottom:20px; font-size:14px">Your Link <div style="margin-bottom:30px">This token will expire in 10 minutes.

Log in into:

<div style="margin-bottom:10px"><a href="https://example.org//Account/api/AAAAAAAAAAA/redeem?**token**=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&apimSubscriptionKey=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ596&realm=NEW-NEW" style="background-color:gray; display:block; width:100px; height:40px; color:#fff; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration:none; line-height:3; margin:0 auto">wmqa-mobile<div style="padding:20px">Kind regards
DDDDDDD<div style="background-color:#DCDCDC; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px"><span style="font-family:sans-serif">This mailbox is unmonitored.Please do not reply to this mail. "
}
}

```
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?%24search=%22Welcome+to%22&select=body&%24top=10&%24skiptoken=MSZZVlF4YWzVDBNeGJFMUhUbXBNVkZFMVQwUm5kRTlFV1hsTlV6QjVXbFV21wbmJXTjZNSGhOUVQwOQ%3d%3d"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be going for the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) providing:

- `token=` as the Left Boundary
- `&` as the Right Boundary

If you want to go for the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) the following regex will do the trick for you:

```
token=(.+?)&
```

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)